# How to use Automator to filter Finder items on network shares

Tags: finder, network, automator, spotlight

I was trying to use the Automator action "Filter Finder Items" and wouldn't get any results, I had a feeling it was because it's a network share the source I'm working with. After a little searching I confirmed it when I read that the source must be indexed by Spotlight for the action to work.

In the Spotlight settings there are options to exclude sources but not to include. How can I either index network shares or work with network shares in Automator?

There are three server actions only:

1. Ask For Servers
2. Connect to Servers
3. Get Specified Servers

All three seem to do the same thing, all three are really vague and don't really work with files not with shares. The shares are already mounted so I used Get Specified Finder Items instead but that doesn't work. So I slid Get Specified Servers on top and still didn't work.

Any ideas? :(

[image]

Comment: Why not just use the `find` _command_ in **Terminal**? With the right _options_, it can get the files you want.

Comment: Mount the external volume from **Finder**, then in **Terminal**: `find /path/to/source -type f -exec mv -v {} /path/to/destination \;` For example: `find /Volumes/media -type f echo -exec mv -v {} $HOME/Music/ \;` Test it, and if the output looks good, run it again without the `echo` in the _command_.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it. To be honest I didn't consider it because I do not know how to use it, I thought about the wildcard-ish recursive `rsync` command, use the `--remove-source-files` option then measure the remaining folders for hints of remaining files, but I'm trying to exhaust my options in Automator first…_that_ and the fact that I barely know how to pipe things in the command line; I don't know how to use variables at all. :/